# Webservice Call Fails : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, webservice-client

I am trying to connect to webservice from Asp.net 1.1 Application. In DEV,TEST environments I dont have any issue. but when we moved to production which are DMZ servers(Windows Server 2003) I was unable to connect to Webservices. It fails as "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive".

I have checked the Firewalls and Port no enabled for webservice. both are fine.

I was spending time from last 2 days in the same issue.

Any one can help on this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to increase the timeout value in IIS?Sometimes when you import a large amount of data this happens

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the Webservice URI (wsdl) from the server.